# Creating VPN by using OpenVPN

Tags: java, android, connection, openvpn, android-10.0

I am facing issue to connect VPN on Android 10 and getting below message in logcat.
This is Error of permissions. Looking for solution.
Also added android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" in Mainfest but not work for me.

D/ConnectionStatus: IO Exceptionjava.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/data/user/0/com.casvpnapp/cache/pie_openvpn.x86_64": error=13, Permission denied

```
D/de.blinkt.openvpn.core.OpenVPNService: onStartCommand: Australia
I/VpnState: VPN_GENERATE_CONFIG  LEVEL_START
D/ConnectionStatus: ---/data/user/0/com.casvpnapp/cache/android.conf
D/ConnectionStatus: ---/data/user/0/com.casvpnapp/cache/android.conf
D/de.blinkt.openvpn.core.OpenVPNService: startOpenVPN: argv:3
D/ConnectionStatus: --[Ljava.lang.String;@ef1521a
I/OpenVPN: Starting openvpn  [Ljava.lang.String;@ef1521a
D/ConnectionStatus: ---29
    startOpenVPNThread---/data/user/0/com.casvpnapp/cache/pie_openvpn.x86_64
D/ConnectionStatus: IO Exceptionjava.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/data/user/0/com.casvpnapp/cache/pie_openvpn.x86_64": error=13, Permission denied
E/OpenVPN: OpenVPNThread Got java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void java.lang.Process.destroy()' on a null object reference
I/VpnState: NOPROCESS No process running. LEVEL_NOTCONNECTED
W/Thread-20: type=1400 audit(0.0:55): avc: granted { execute } for name="pie_openvpn.x86_64" dev="vdc" ino=23035 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c139,c256,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:app_data_file:s0:c139,c256,c512,c768 tclass=file app=com.casvpnapp
I/OpenVPN: Exiting
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems it's a problem with your OpenVPN library.
Although I have also developed a VPN app based on the OpenVPN library it's working fine for me. You can check my source code.

https://github.com/ashraf789/Cake-VPN

Comment: Thank you Mr. @Vicky . The problem is solved now you could use on android 30 too

Comment: @Ashraf789 it is not working on minSdkVersion > 22. How to handle this?

Comment: well, let me check.

Comment: @Ashraf789 Can you tell me how you solve the problem for targetSdkVersion 29

Comment: @Sundeep Badhotiya
I have updated the source code with the latest ics open vpn source code.

Comment: @Ashraf789 May i know where you have updated the source code

Comment: Full library replaces with the new library. 
https://github.com/schwabe/ics-openvpn/tree/master/main/src/main

Comment: One of the contributors solve the issue here is the details
https://github.com/ashraf789/Cake-VPN/issues/34

Comment: I am not able to connect for targetSdkVersion 29, could you please suggest what i should do. I copied form your repo,  if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.P)
            return new File(context.getApplicationInfo().nativeLibraryDir, "libovpnexec.so").getPath(); 
but it actually stuck at add-route  case for ipv6 while making connection.

Comment: how can i use your plugin in flutter?

Comment: I am sorry, I am not familiar with flutter.

Answer (score 9):

I recently ran into exactly same issue. I was using clone of EasyVPN-Free. After close examination I found that most of these apps are using same approach and using older versions of ics-openvpn core.

Looks like you are also using older version ics-openvpn in your app which was not compatible with android 10 as its trying to start a process by loading ovpn binary from assets (instead of using JNI lib for this) which is prohibited by Android 10.

To fix this issue find following method in Class **VPNLaunchHelper.java**:

```
private static String writeMiniVPN(Context context)
```

**Add** following lines in the beginning

```
String nativeAPI = NativeUtils.getNativeAPI();
/* Q does not allow executing binaries written in temp directory anymore */
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.P)
    return new File(context.getApplicationInfo().nativeLibraryDir, "libovpnexec.so").getPath();
```

Now find the following line and **comment / remove** it:

```
String nativeAPI = NativeUtils.getNativeAPI();
```

**[Update]**

As originally suggested by Md. Ikramul Murad

**Add** below code in manifest file:

```
<application     android:extractNativeLibs="true"     ... >
```

Now get **libovpnexec.so** for your target platforms and paste them appropriately in **jniLibs** folder of your app this should fix your exception on android.

You can refer to this [EasyVPN-Free](https://github.com/mehroz1/EasyVPN-Free) fork which i have specifically made to fix this issue.

I hope that this will help all others who might ran into same issue.

Comment: Please note that is is NOT recommend. Instead of band aid fixing an old version of the software using a library that you didn't built yourself, you should just use the latest version of the upstream software.As VPN software is security sensitive, there is no excuse in using old versions.

Comment: True. Its just a band aid for those who want to temporarily fix the problem. The proper way of doing this is to upgrade the library to latest version.

Comment: I've followed your instruction and added libovpnexec.so file in the jniLibs folder. But I've got below error:

 ```W/System.err: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/data/app/<appID>-<Token>==/lib/arm64/libovpnexec.so": error=2, No such file or directory```

Comment: I've added below code in manifest file:

```<application
    android:extractNativeLibs="true"
    ...
>```

Now it's working fine.

Comment: Thanks, this worked like a charm! As @Md.IkramulMurad said we have to add this tag in the manifest file along with changes in VPNLaunchHelper.java.
 <application     android:extractNativeLibs="true"  >

Comment: @FarhanAnwar, please upvote my comment if you found it helpful.

Comment: Also, insert `add_executable(libovpnexec.so minivpn/minivpn.c)
target_compile_options(libovpnexec.so  PRIVATE -fPIE)
target_link_libraries(libovpnexec.so  PRIVATE openvpn -fPIE -pie)` into `CMakeLists.txt` before the first occurance of `minivpn` in that file.