# openVPN not working on Android 10 in androidstudio

Tags: java, android

hi i use this project in my app :
https://github.com/schwabe/ics-openvpn
and write a vpn application 
its work fine on all android version because on android 10 i give this error on logcat :

```
2020-04-01 01:47:56.914 2540-2839/com.vpnfree.approid I/OpenVPN: Starting openvpn
2020-04-01 01:47:56.920 2540-2839/com.vpnfree.approid E/OpenVPN: OpenVPNThread Got java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void java.lang.Process.destroy()' on a null object reference
2020-04-01 01:47:56.920 2540-2839/com.packagename.approid E/level: LEVEL_NOTCONNECTED
2020-04-01 01:47:56.959 2540-2839/com.packagename.approid I/OpenVPN: Exiting
```

Comment: Is this problem solved already?

Answer (score 1):

```
        android:extractNativeLibs="true"
        tools:replace="android:extractNativeLibs"
```

Add This Two Lines In Your Manifest Application

Answer (score 0):

It's not working because when you call `destroy()`, you are calling it on a null object. This is throwing an NPE can preventing you from connecting.

Comment: i dont call destroy() !! :)

Comment: Your stack trace says otherwise :) But it could be called via your SDK. Without seeing your code, it's hard to say.

Answer (score 0):

This null pointer exception can be the result of process builder starting a new process by loading a binary from assets which is not supported by android.

You can confirm this case by using `e.printStackTrace();` in **`catch`** clause near **line 187 - line 188** of method `private void startOpenVPNThreadArgs(String[] argv)` which can be found in **OpenVPNThread.java**.

If you get error 13 in your log cat like this:

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "...": error=13, Permission denied
```

Then you might be using older version of ics-openvpn. In this case please refer to this:

- [My answer to: "Creating VPN by using OpenVPN"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64373156/7173141)
- [My comment on the "What change in API 29" issue in the  schwabe /
  ics-openvpn GitHub repository](https://github.com/schwabe/ics-openvpn/issues/1179#issuecomment-709324457)

I hope that this will resolve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Just add this line in your project's `gradle.properties` file:

```
android.bundle.enableUncompressedNativeLibs=false
```

`.aab` file handles the `.so` files a bit differently, that's why VPN was not working in `.aab` bundle releases.